# Escaping double-slashes with regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, unicode, replaceall

I have this unit test:

```
public void testDeEscapeResponse() {
    final String[] inputs = new String[] {"peque\\\\u0f1o", "peque\\u0f1o"};
    final String[] expected = new String[] {"peque\\u0f1o", "peque\\u0f1o"};
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        final String input = inputs[i];
        final String actual = QTIResultParser.deEscapeResponse(input);
        Assert.assertEquals(
            "deEscapeResponse did not work correctly", expected[i], actual);
    }
}
```

I have this method:

```
static String deEscapeResponse(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");
}
```

The unit test is failing with this error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:703)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
    at com.acme.MyClass.deEscapeResponse
    at com.acme.MyClassTest.testDeEscapeResponse
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) which does a literal replacement instead of [`String.replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which uses regular expressions.

**Example:**

```
"peque\\\\u0f1o".replace("\\\\", "\\")    //  gives  peque\u0f1o
```

---

`String.replaceAll` takes a regular expression thus `\\\\` is interpreted as the *expression* `\\` which in turn matches a single `\`. (The replacement string also has special treatment for `\` so there's an error there too.)

To make `String.replaceAll` work as you expect here, you would need to do

```
"peque\\\\u0f1o".replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\")
```

Comment: You know, I thought about using replace, but I thought it was exactly the same as replaceAll, except that it only replaced the first instance.  Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, I can see why you thought so when there is a replace*All* method :-)

Comment: ...though there is actually a [`String.replaceFirst`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method for that :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're using replaceAll() instead of replace(). replaceAll expects a regular expression in the first field and you're just trying to string match.

Answer (score 1):

See javadoc for [`Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar
>   signs ($) in the replacement string
>   may cause the results to be different
>   than if it were being treated as a
>   literal replacement string. Dollar
>   signs may be treated as references to
>   captured subsequences as described
>   above, and backslashes are used to
>   escape literal characters in the
>   replacement string.

Thus with `replaceAll` you cannot replace anything with a backslash. Thus a really crazy workaround for your case would be `str.replaceAll("\\\\(\\\\)", "$1")`