# Java - replace all instances of path separators with system path separator

Tags: java, regex

I've taken the regex matching both slash and backslash from this answer: [Regex to match both slash in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789504/regex-to-match-both-slash-in-java)

```
    String path = "C:\\system/properties\\\\all//";
    String replaced = path.replaceAll("[/\\\\]+", 
        System.getProperty("file.separator"));
```

However, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 1

What is wrong with this regex? Removing `+` doesn't change anything, the error message is the same...

Comment: Could you use the `Path` class here instead? Its only available in java 7, just making you aware of its existence.

Comment: `replace()` vs `replaceAll()` !!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping double-slashes with regular expressions in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348847/escaping-double-slashes-with-regular-expressions-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is documented in [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

So you can try this:

```
String replaced = path.replaceAll("[/\\\\]+", Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.
            getProperty("file.separator")));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
String path = "C:\\system/properties\\\\all//";
```

**Edit: modified following contents of assylias' answer**

```
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("(\\\\+|/+)", Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("file.separator"))));
```

**End of edit**

Output (for me - I use a mac):

```
C:/system/properties/all/
```

So it will "normalize" the double separators.

Comment: You will have a problem with this on Windows tho due to the backslash characters

Comment: @Reimeus how come? This has a forward slash in the output because I use a mac, but in Windows it would output a backslash - that's the whole point of the System property. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: The problem is not the regex but rather the replacement `String`, see assylias answer

Comment: @Reimeus oh... right! Got it now :D Editing my answer. Thanks!